# Generic <T> and 2 base class inheritance

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

I have a question and am getting a little stumped on this one. It's probably easy but I'm just missing it.

If I have a class what contains necessary structures and the structures can inherit. I need a generic method what that an be passed to and then used. For example, let's say I have a structure Test, Test-A which inherits from Test. Then I have a MyTest and MyTest-B both which inherit from Test-A.

How can I create a method using T so that I can supply both MyTest and MyTest-B and I can use either of them in the method?

So:

```
public class Test
{
    public int Hello {get; set; }
}

pubilc class Test-A : Test
{  
   public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class MyTest : Test-A
{
   public string Last { get; set; } 
}

public class MYTest-B : Test-A
{
   public int Age {get; set; }
}
```

I need a method like:

```
private void MyList<T>(List<T> TestList) where T : **{not sure what this would be}**
{
    TestList.Age = 10;

    **OR** 

    TestList.Name = "Jane";
}
```

How or what am I missing (or not understanding) to be able to do that?

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This will confuse you and many here will hate me for "screwing up" a language because of posting this :) but c# allows dynamics. Though avoid using them even though they are f***ing cool http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx

Comment: Event VB has that with a variant type and with an object type but then are somewhat risky. C# 4.0 now has the optional parameter aspects as well now.

Comment: No risk no fun. I am joking :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no constraint you could use which would match both of those conditions.  The only way to handle this would be to use two, overloaded methods, as there is no shared contract.

Generic constraints only work if there is a base class or interface shared which all types implement, and use the same contract (ie: both have `Name` **and** `Age` properties).

Comment: I was about to write an answer but yours is nice and succinct.

Comment: Is there a where to do it without using the inheritance aspect then? So, I use a List<T> TestList but without the where. Then have reflection or something determine which to use **Name** or **Age**?

Comment: @user2887486 Just use overloaded methods - have a method that accepts `List<MyTest>` and a separate method that takes `List<MyTest-B>`...

Comment: Hmmm...understand what you are getting at on the overloads. I am looking at attempting to capitalize on some of the aspects. This might be an area that a optional parameter in a method call can be used now that C# 4.0 actually has it. I will look at exploring that one. That might work and if so I will surely give you the answer. :-)

Comment: @user2887486 Note that, even if you use one method, you'd have to do some form of branching within the method (ie: if "Age" exists, do this, otherwise, do this).  Refactoring out the shared information and using 2 methods is often simpler and easier to maintain later.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I create a method using T so that I can supply both **MyTest** and
>   MyTest-B and I can use either of them in the method?

```
     **TestList.Age = 10;**

     ...
```

How would this work if you passed in an object of type `MyTest`, given that `MyTest` doesn't have an `Age` property?

Comment: MyTest-B has the Age. MyTest doesn't. But I am looking at how I can do a generic where IF Age is there then I can use it otherwise I cannot, obviously.